# Spring Boot disable @Cacheable per request

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot, spring-cache

I'm trying to disable a `Cacheable` function in Spring Boot based on a URL parameter. For example http://myapplication.com/some/request?cache=false

I tried the condition with SpEL but I haven't been able to get it work

```
@Cacheable(value = "value", keyGenerator = "keygenerator", condition = "#{someComponent.isCacheEnabled()}")
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `someComponent` ?

Comment: I'm guessing someComponent would be bean that is aware of the url parameter as @john-blum suggests below

Answer (score 0):

user4843-

I am assuming your "arbitrary component" (i.e. `someComponent`) is a *Spring* managed bean in your *Spring* `ApplicationContext`?

If so, then you have not properly referenced this *Spring* managed bean using the SpEL expression specified on the `condition` attribute inside your `@Cacheable` annotation  declaration.  It should read...

```
condition="#{@someComponent.isCacheEnabled()}"
```

Notice the use of the `@` symbol on `someComponent`, which is explained in more detail [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions-bean-references). And, although the *Spring* [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-spel-context) is less than clear on the matter, it does imply the SpEL evaluation context created and used inside *Spring's Cache Abstraction* when processing the caching annotations uses "the built-in parameters", or [SpEL conventions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions-language-ref), in addition to the ones listed in *Table 36.1 - Cache SpEL available metadata*.  See examples [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition).

I would also caution you on your use of some arbitrary component, or *Spring* managed bean to manage caching state for your entire application like this.

1. First, if `someComponent` is a *Singleton* bean (the default in the *Spring* container) then this bean would need to be Thread-safe, particularly as its state is changing, possibly and seemingly with every HTTP request, which leads me to...
2. I am not sure you want a *Spring* managed bean managing the "cacheable state" of your application service/repository methods if the caching state is conditional on each and every individual HTTP request, particularly since most HTTP containers process each HTTP request in a separate Thread.  You are most certainly going to run into race conditions.  In this case, I'd rather use an additional cacheable service method parameter to determine the cacheable state of that particular service method invocation, stemming from the HTTP request.

Example:

```
@Cacheable(value = "value", keyGenerator="keyGenerator" conditional="#enableCaching")
public <return-type> someCacheableServiceMethod(..., boolean enableCaching) {
  ...
}
```

In fact, I'd even suggest using more intelligible business-oriented rules to determine the cacheable state of your service methods.

Hope this helps!

-John

Comment: Thanks!  I will give this a try.  Note my use case for disabling caching is for developers using the api that want to make sure the data is getting pulled from the datasource (in this case Postgres).  One might argue this is a "hack"